# Is there a more elegant solution than this spaghetti code without completely revamping the whole page?

Tags: php, array

I use 'GROUP_CONCAT' to get comma separated lists of a person's educational background.  Included in those lists are the type of degree, major, issuing establishment, and year received.  `degreeType` is a required field and cannot empty.  Prior to looping, I split the lists into arrays, like so:

```
$degreeType = explode(",", $degreeType);
$major = explode(",", $major);
$issuingEstablishment = explode(",", $issuingEstablishment);
$yearReceived = explode(",", $yearReceived);
```

I can then do a `foreach` loop and echo out the information returned.  However, since `explode()` returns an array, even if it's empty, I have to check it first before starting the `foreach`.  As shown below:

```
$counter = 0;
//echo out education
if($degreeType[0]!=""){
  foreach($degreeType as $dType) {
    if($counter == 0) $info .= "<h2>Educational Background</h2><ul>";
    $info .= "<li>$dType - ";
    $info .= ($major[$counter]!="") ? "$major[$counter], " : "";
    $info .= $issuingEstablishment[$counter];
    $info .= ($yearReceived[$counter]!="") ? ", $yearReceived[$counter]" : "";
    $info .= "</li>";
    $counter++;
  }
  $info .= "</ul>";
}
```

Alternatively, I could run a check prior to separating the lists.  Either solution seems inelegant.  Is there a cleaner/faster/better way to split the lists and loop through them, but only if they actually contain information?  Initially I was going to dabble with using an `object`, but `mysqli` doesn't support that with prepared statements.  Any advice is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your script is alright, there are just some minor issues:

1.) If string is enclosed inside `""` then PHP interpreter checks whether there are some variables or not, if string is enclosed inside `''` PHP interpreter does not check it.

2.) You forgot to declare `$info` variable, it is always good to declare your variables before doing some operations on them like `.=`.

3.) I don't like using this shorter syntax, because it can be source of bugs which are hard to find, in my opinion it is usually better to use `{}`:

`if($counter == 0) $info .= "<h2>Educational Background</h2><ul>";`

4.) You don't need to repeat `$info .=` on every line, it can be replaced by `.`.

I rewrote the script in respect to previously mentioned points:

```
$degreeType = explode(',', $degreeType);
$major = explode(',', $major);
$issuingEstablishment = explode(',', $issuingEstablishment);
$yearReceived = explode(',', $yearReceived);

$counter = 0;
$info = '';
if($degreeType[0] != ''){
    foreach($degreeType as $dType) {
        if(!$counter) {
            $info .= '<h2>Educational Background</h2><ul>';
        }

        $info .= "<li>$dType - "
            . (($major[$counter] != '') ? "$major[$counter], " : '')
            . $issuingEstablishment[$counter]
            . (($yearReceived[$counter] != '') ? ", $yearReceived[$counter]" : '')
            . '</li>'
        ;

        $counter++;
    }
    $info .= "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: Oops! I forgot to copy-n-paste the `info` initialization, but it was in the original.  Thanks for the tips, incorporating them now!